# Toast Alert SwiftUI display problems

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm currently trying to use the [AlertToast](https://github.com/elai950/AlertToast) in my SwiftUI project, the alert seems to be working but it looks like it is being displayed in the button that it is called from.

Attaching an example:

[image: Toast Alerts SwiftUI]

My Code:

```
struct ButtonsGroup: View {
@State private var showingAlert = false
@State private var showingSheet = false
@State private var showingActionSheet = false
@State private var showButtonSheet = false
@State private var showToast = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{

                Button("Show Toast"){
                     showToast.toggle()
                }
            }
            .toast(isPresenting: $showToast){

                // `.alert` is the default displayMode
                AlertToast(displayMode: .banner(.slide), type: .regular, title: "Message Sent!")
                
                //Choose .hud to toast alert from the top of the screen
                //AlertToast(displayMode: .hud, type: .regular, title: "Message Sent!")
                
                //Choose .banner to slide/pop alert from the bottom of the screen
                //AlertToast(displayMode: .banner(.slide), type: .regular, title: "Message Sent!")
            }
}
}
```

I've looked up the documentation and copy the code, but it seems that the problem persists.

My Goal is to show the alert either at the top of the screen, or the middle.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use the `.hud` instead

Comment: @aheze is correct, as documentation says `Choose .hud to toast alert from the top of the screen`. `.alert` displays it right on top of container view

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Sadly by doing that im getting an error: [SwiftUI] Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite).

Comment: Hmm is that happening when you do `showToast.toggle()`? Might be a bug in the library.